# Laravel websocket cant connect to pusher ERR_CERT_AUTHORITY_INVALID

Tags: php, laravel, websocket, real-time, laravel-websockets

I have a laravel application with websockets. I already setup all the needs for the websocket and pusher config. But whenever I test my broadcast channel I got

`app.js:58283 WebSocket connection to 'wss://127.0.0.1/app/644a4ac1988060882370?protocol=7&client=js&version=6.0.2&flash=false' failed: Error in connection establishment: net::ERR_CERT_AUTHORITY_INVALID`

When i do some reload. sometimes i get
`app.js:55791 WebSocket connection to 'wss://127.0.0.1/app/644a4ac1988060882370?protocol=7&client=js&version=6.0.2&flash=false' failed: WebSocket is closed before the connection is established.`

Here are my configs.

broadcasting.php

```
   'pusher' => [
            'driver' => 'pusher',
            'key' => env('PUSHER_APP_KEY'),
            'secret' => env('PUSHER_APP_SECRET'),
            'app_id' => env('PUSHER_APP_ID'),
            'options' => [
                'cluster' => env('PUSHER_APP_CLUSTER'),
                'encrypted' => true,
                'host' => '127.0.0.1',
                'port' => 6001,
                'scheme' => 'http',
            ],
        ],
```

websockets.php

```
  'apps' => [
        [
            'id' => env('PUSHER_APP_ID'),
            'name' => env('APP_NAME'),
            'key' => env('PUSHER_APP_KEY'),
            'secret' => env('PUSHER_APP_SECRET'),
            'path' => env('PUSHER_APP_PATH'),
            'capacity' => null,
            'enable_client_messages' => false,
            'enable_statistics' => true,
            'verify_peer' => false,
        ],
    ],
```

bootstrap.js

```
import Echo from "laravel-echo"
window.Pusher = require('pusher-js');

window.Echo = new Echo({
    broadcaster: 'pusher',
    key: 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx',
    wsHost: window.location.hostname,
    wsPort: 6001,
    disableStats: true,
    // enabledTransports: ['ws', 'wss']
});

window.Echo.channel('Inventory').listen('InventoryEvent',(e)=>{
    console.log(e)
})
```

web.php

```
Route::get('/', function () {
    broadcast(new InventoryEvent('somedata'));
    return view('welcome');
});
```

InventoryEvent

```
namespace App\Events;

use Illuminate\Broadcasting\Channel;
use Illuminate\Broadcasting\InteractsWithSockets;
use Illuminate\Broadcasting\PresenceChannel;
use Illuminate\Broadcasting\PrivateChannel;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Broadcasting\ShouldBroadcast;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Events\Dispatchable;
use Illuminate\Queue\SerializesModels;

class InventoryEvent implements ShouldBroadcast
{
    use Dispatchable, InteractsWithSockets, SerializesModels;

    public $somedata;

    /**
     * Create a new event instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct($somedata)
    {
        $this->somedata = $somedata;
    }

    /**
     * Get the channels the event should broadcast on.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Broadcasting\Channel|array
     */
    public function broadcastOn()
    {
        return new Channel('Inventory');
    }
}
```

package.json

```
    "devDependencies": {
        "axios": "^0.19",
        "bootstrap": "^4.0.0",
        "cross-env": "^7.0",
        "jquery": "^3.2",
        "laravel-mix": "^5.0.1",
        "lodash": "^4.17.13",
        "popper.js": "^1.12",
        "resolve-url-loader": "2.3.1",
        "sass": "^1.20.1",
        "sass-loader": "7.*",
        "vue": "^2.5.17",
        "vue-template-compiler": "^2.6.10"
    },
    "dependencies": {
        "admin-lte": "^3.0.4",
        "fusioncharts": "^3.15.1-sr.1",
        "laravel-echo": "^1.7.0",
        "pusher-js": "^6.0.2",
        "sweetalert2": "^9.10.9",
        "vue-fusioncharts": "^3.0.4",
        "vue-moment": "^4.1.0",
        "vue-router": "^3.1.6",
        "vue-select": "^3.9.5"
    }
```

I already setup the env for my pusher credentials. Do i need to config something in my pusher in order for this to work? I got another project with the same setup but it works but this one is not.

Comment: are you in production? does your server use https i.e. has a ssl certificate?

Comment: no, I am using my local computer/localhost @UzairRiaz

Comment: in **broadcasting.php** set `'encrypted' => false` for `options`. run `php artisan optimize:clear` and try again. If it works I'll post it as an answer so you can accept it.

Comment: I tried that before but it does not work for me @UzairRiaz

Comment: set encrypted to false anyway, its supposed to be true only for production. After that, run `php artisan websockets:serve` if you are not already and try connecting to your dashboard, which you can access at **{your_base_app_url}/laravel-websockets**. If it connects successfully, your config is good. I can guide you further from there.

Comment: I even tried that @UzairRiaz. well i can access the websocket admin. but i got an SSL error. and events dont trigger

Comment: How do you know events don't trigger? try running `php artisan queue:work` in another terminal along with `websockets:serve`. It dispatches your queued events.

Comment: because when i visit my home, the `console.log` command will print something. but when i visit home it says `ERR_CERT_AUTHORITY_INVALID`

Comment: see my `bootstrap.js` and `web.php`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/213255/discussion-between-uzair-riaz-and-vince).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try downgrading your `pusher-js` package to version `4.3.1`. Thats what I am using and it works well. Latest version always seems to listen on secure `wss` instead of the non-secure `ws`.

Comment: Had to spend hours until I found this! Thanks it works like a charm after downgrading!

Comment: Or you can add `forceTLS: false` to your Laravel Echo configuration and it'll work just as fine. :)

Comment: It still doesn't work for me

Answer (score 18):

in your bootstrap.js file, try changing:

```
import Echo from "laravel-echo"
window.Pusher = require('pusher-js');

window.Echo = new Echo({
    broadcaster: 'pusher',
    key: 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx',
    wsHost: window.location.hostname,
    wsPort: 6001,
    disableStats: true,
    forceTLS: false, //<<<<=====CHANGE THIS
    // enabledTransports: ['ws', 'wss']
});

window.Echo.channel('Inventory').listen('InventoryEvent',(e)=>{
    console.log(e)
})
```

the default value of the forceTLS option is true, which forces listening on wss instead of ws.

Comment: This should be accepted solution. Downgrading to lower version could be a solution but older versions might not be as safe in terms of security

Comment: @Armand I'm not sure how potentially connecting without encryption would assuage any security concerns?

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar issue. I did a whole lots of debugging not knowing I was missing a very simple thing which wasn't so simple after all:) In my ../config/websockets.php file only one IP address was permitted. I had to comment it

```
'allowed_origins' => [
    //'124.0.0.1',
    //
],
```

Answer (score 1):

1. In laravel config/broadcasting.php , in 'pusher' config, under 'options' I've set the 'encrypted' to false
2. In my laravel resources/js/bootstrap.js is set the forceTLS to
   false, and encrypted to false, example:

   window.Echo = new Echo({
   broadcaster: 'pusher',
   key: import.meta.env.VITE_PUSHER_APP_KEY,
   cluster: import.meta.env.VITE_PUSHER_APP_CLUSTER ?? 'mt1',
   wsHost: import.meta.env.VITE_PUSHER_HOST, // Use wssHost instead of wsHost
   wssHost: import.meta.env.VITE_PUSHER_HOST, // Use wssHost instead of wsHost
   wssPort: import.meta.env.VITE_PUSHER_PORT, // Use wssPort instead of wsPort
   wsPort: import.meta.env.VITE_PUSHER_PORT, // Use wssPort instead of wsPort
   forceTLS: false, // Set forceTLS to true for secure connection
   encrypted: false, // Set encrypted to true for secure connection
   disableStats: true,
   enabledTransports: ['ws', 'wss'], // Specify wss as the only transport
   });
3. I've set PUSHER_SCHEME=http in .env file
4. I've opened my app exclusively with "http://" protocol, on one browser and on another browser on my server / same computer / dev computer. Real time communication works from one side to another in my webchat app!!

But then I've tried to send a message from mobile + mobile internet (outside wifi - external), and in my computer it listened for the event properly and showed the new message.. but when I send from the computer, on my phone I don't get the real time message / it seems to not listen... I wonder if it's the same problem because of being "WS" or "WSS" (secure connection or not).
Any idea anyone? Github repo: https://github.com/Pablo-Camara/Chat-Rooms

I'm still to try from external net / phone to external net / phone, but somethings tells me it won't work. Edit: I tested from virtual computer/browser on Edge, and another Firefox, and between them the communication is not real time! only on my host machine it works! could it be something on cloudflare? could it be that i really need to setup secure soketi / websocket connection? "wss" instead of "ws" ?

Answer (score 1):

For some cases you have just to run websockets with sudo:
sudo php artisan websockets:serve